# Black screen on GRUB with AMD RX 550

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, amdgpu

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But, I'm getting a black screen. I can start Windows from boot menu (not GRUB). But when I will try to boot Ubuntu, I can't see anything. Just black screen. What can I do? My GPU is AMD RX 550 and my CPU is Intel i5-10400F.

Comment: Likely a video driver issue.    Could be wrong driver or buggy driver.

Comment: If you are still having problems with this, please give operating system version and, if you can, AMD driver version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing the proprietary drivers from the AMD support site here:

https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-550

Comment: Could you provide instructions on how to do this in your post? Thanks.